# What is a Muslim expected to know of the Torah?

Tags: scripture

I'm reading and English version of the Quran and I'm running into difficulty. It references stories similar to those presented in the Old Testament but with some variations.

Were the first Muslims hearing these stories for the first time when the Quran was given or was there a body of knowledge everyone already knew?

The stories don't cover the full narrative of the Old Testament and it is not always apparent when in the Torah these stories should go. Is there a Muslim version of the Old Testament that has the correct narrative as a full text (and without the laws the Jews invented)? How, historically, were Muslims educated on these matters?